# ar_kinect compile error conversion from ‘tf::Transform’ to non-scalar type ‘btTransform’ requested

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to rosmake the ar_kinect package on Ubuntu 11.10 and I get the following error. It is the last package I need to before running the mini_max grasp object tutorial, so any help would be appreciated.
I also get a lot of warnings prior to the error, so I have included those as well.
Thanks,
-Scott

### Full error:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ar_kinect.dir/src/ar_kinect.o
In file included from /home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/include/ar_kinect/ar_kinect.h:52:0,
from /home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:27:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: In static member function ‘static sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void >::Ptr sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:408:55: warning: ‘static bool sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromIpltoRosImage(const IplImage*, sensor_msgs::Image&, std::string)’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:307) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp: In constructor ‘ar_pose::ARPublisher::ARPublisher(ros::NodeHandle&)’:
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:62:75: warning: ‘sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp: In member function ‘void ar_pose::ARPublisher::getTransformationCallback(const PointCloud2ConstPtr&)’:
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:230:7: error: ‘estimateRigidTransformationSVD’ is not a member of ‘pcl’
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:236:43: error: conversion from ‘tf::Matrix3x3’ to non-scalar type ‘btMatrix3x3’ requested
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:237:44: error: conversion from ‘tf::Vector3’ to non-scalar type ‘btVector3’ requested
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:254:34: warning: name lookup of ‘i’ changed [enabled by default]
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:145:9: warning:   matches this ‘i’ under ISO standard rules [enabled by default]
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:239:15: warning:   matches this ‘i’ under old rules [enabled by default]
/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/src/ar_kinect.cpp:280:46: error: conversion from ‘tf::Transform’ to non-scalar type ‘btTransform’ requested
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ar_kinect.dir/src/ar_kinect.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ar_kinect.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/scott/ros_packages/ar_kinect/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ar_kinect written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/scott/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120718-115102/ar_kinect/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< ar_kinect [FAIL] [ 8.44 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ar_kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39183/ar_kinect-compile-error-conversion-from-%E2%80%98tf::transform%E2%80%99-to-non-scalar-type-%E2%80%98bttransform%E2%80%99-requested/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error most likely has to do with changes to the tf datatypes for fuerte as described in [this migration guide](http://ros.org/wiki/geometry/bullet_migration). If there is no migrated version available, you probably have to fix the package yourself for fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-11-19**:
in the page you mentioned, I solved my problems running the scritpt:
rosrun tf bullet_migration_sed.py

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else having this trouble, I submitted a patch to fergs' google code site. It got everything working for me.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1